Intuition: Why is quadratic variation finite for martingales
(Disclaimer: I'm not well-read in this topic, so might be getting some details wrong. Hopefully not wrong enough to make my question for intuition moot)
For any martingale $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with $X_0=0$, the quadratic variation $[X]_t$ satisfies
$$
E[[X]_t] = E[X_t^2].
$$
The proof of this is elementary and intuitive, and many introductory lecture notes don't go beyond special cases like continuous square-integrable martingales, so one could be forgiven to think that quadratic variation is inherently linked to square integrability. In fact, I found the quote "The conclusion to be drawn from Theorem 5.8 and Problems 5.11 and 5.12 is that for continuous, square-integrable martingales, quadratic variation is the 'right' variation to study. " from Karatzas and Shreve (although I don't have the full book at hand, so this may be out of context.
However, it turns out that quadratic variation is well-defined and finite ($\forall t\geq 0: [X]_t<\infty \;\text{a.s.}$) for all martingales (discontinuous semi-martingales, even) and it's merely the expected value of quadratic variation that requires square integrability, which leads to my question:
Is there a good intuition for why quadratic variation exists and is finite for all martingales, i.e., why $L^1$ + vanishing of some expectation implies existence of something that involves squares?
Intuitively, what makes it such that past trajectories of stochastic processes with rougher paths (e.g., fractional Brownian motion) must carry information about forward expectations? Conversely, what property of martingales makes it such that they cannot jump back and forth fast enough so to have infinite quadratic variation (and instead, say, finite quartic variation)?

Could you please be a little bit more precise about what you mean by "finite" here?  Is the claim that for any martingale $M$, $[M]_t < \infty$ a.s. for all $t > 0$?

@user6247850 Yes, I thought that's true. Is it not?

Oh, maybe that requires that the maximum process is $L^1$, not just any fixed $M_t$

@user6247850 I think it's always true, but all I have to prove it is a comment by Nate Eldredge at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354808/prove-that-fractional-brownian-motion-is-not-a-semimartingale-using-the-p-variat I first thought a combination of BDG and Doob's inequality showed this, but then found out that Doob's inequality doesn't hold for $p=1$

Is this not just a consequence of the existence of stochastic integrals? https://www.planetmath.org/quadraticvariationofasemimartingale

@Eric that sounds plausible, although I don't know enough about general stochastic integrals to know why the ones involved in defining quadratic variation are not just well-defined but also finite. Assuming they are: for you, is this the way your intuition goes about why quadratic variation exists? "Stochastic integrals obviously exist (and are finite) for general martingales, so quadratic variation also exists (and is finite)" for general martingales"?
